# "sort -g" does not work as expected on data in scientific notation

Tags: sort, locale, numeric-data

I am trying to sort a data file in descending order. The data file is given by three columns delimited by tabs; I want to order them in descending order for the third column with (the third column is given as a scientific notation in exponential value):

```
cat eII_surf.txt | sort -gr -k3
```

Somehow, this worked on a previous machine, but my new one does not seem to do the trick at all.

Here a simple example:

`cat test.txt`:

```
6.7 2.3e-12
5.0 3.4e-18
4.5 5.6e-16
4.2 2.1e-15
4.0 2.9e-17
2.4 2.5e-15
1.0 1.0e-17
0.5 1.0e-18
```

and `cat test.txt | sort -gr -k2`:

```
4.5 5.6e-16
5.0 3.4e-18
6.7 2.3e-12
4.2 2.1e-15
4.0 2.9e-17
2.4 2.5e-15
1.0 1.0e-17
0.5 1.0e-18
```

This is the output of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.utf8
LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.utf8
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: None of the "failed sorted" is in the example input file. What do you get if you sort the example set of data you've shown us? What do you expect to get? Are the columns separated by a tab or by (multiple) spaces?

Comment: Is the question supposed to show the input and corresponding output? The data do not match. If you ran the command on a big file and copied parts of the data only, you should instead create a smaller input file and show the expected and actual output for this input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`2.3e-12` would be understood as `2` in a locale where the decimal radix character is `,` (as it is in most of the non-English speaking world including your `de_DE.utf8`) where the number would need to be written `2,3e-12`.

You could do:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -grk2 < your-file
```

To force numbers being interpreted in the English style.

In the C locale (the only one you would be guaranteed to find on any system), the decimal radix is `.` (conveniently for your input).

Note that `sort` has nothing to do with `bash`, it's a separate command. The `-g` option is a non-standard extension of the GNU implementation of `sort`.

Comment: Thanks! That one seems to work. Would you recommend to set up LC_ALL=C in the bashrc as a new environment variable?

Comment: @LukasFuchs, no I wouldn't. You'd want to use `LC_ALL=C` only for commands where you don't want the behaviour to be affected by the user's localisation preferences. See [What does "LC\_ALL=C" do?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763)